# Slackbot Attachment - Is something wrong with this?

Tags: slack-api

I am using botkit by howdy to make the api call for postMessage method. Its giving me `invalid_array_arg` error when I am passing attachment property. Is something wrong with the way its getting POSTed

```
bot.api.chat.postMessage(
        {
            channel : '#general',
            text    : 'hi',
            parse   : true,
            username: '@' + bot.identity.name,
            as_user : true,
            icon_url: listOfMessages.logoUrl,
            attachments: [{"pretext": "pre-hello", "text": "text-world"}]

        }, function (err,res) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
            console.log(res);
        }
    );
```

Comment: Error message from the Slack documentation: `The method was passed a PHP-style array argument (e.g. with a name like foo[7]). These are never valid with the Slack API.` [Link](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was running into this same issue and fixed it by stringifying the array.

```
attachments: JSON.stringify([{"pretext": "pre-hello", "text": "text-world"}])
```

Comment: had the same problem in the ruby slack-api gem.

the important thing is to convert the whole attachments array to json, not just the object in the attachments, for example:

`attachments: [attachment].to_json`

Comment: It is actually noted as a part of the [Slack API documentation](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.update): "_The optional attachments argument should contain a JSON-encoded array of attachments..._"

Comment: but https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage/test this is also not working  and attachments need to be Required to add text which posts only text on slack